# Force header in odd page on the right

Tags: header-footer

I use this following code for header, but the header is on both odd and even page on the left. What could I change to make the header only on right odd page ?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[nocheck]{fancyhdr}% header
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyhead[L]{\chaptername\ \thechapter\ --\ \leftmark}
```

Comment: `\documentclass[twoside]{report}`or only the odd page style is used